# Find the overlapping information

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, join

```
CREATE temp TABLE players
( 
    id                    smallint,
    player_id            smallint,
    team                 varchar(20),
    start_dt             date,
    end_dt               date
);

insert into players (id, player_id, team, start_dt, end_dt) values 
(1,100,'TEAM-A','2018-01-01','2018-08-15'),
(2,100,'TEAM-B','2018-11-15',NULL),
(3,101,'TEAM-B','2018-05-15','2019-02-15'),
(4,101,'TEAM-C','2019-04-01','2019-09-15'),
(5,101,'TEAM-A','2019-11-01',NULL),
(6,102,'TEAM-B','2018-01-15','2019-02-15'),
(7,102,'TEAM-C','2019-05-15','2019-08-01'),
(8,102,'TEAM-A','2019-09-01', NULL  ),
(9,103,'TEAM-C','2019-01-01','2019-06-15')
;
```

From the above sample input data, I need to find the overlapping information as below -

[image]

I tried to accomplish this using the overlap option, but it didn't give me the expected result.
any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for pairs of players that did belong to the same team at a given point in time.

You can self-join the table with proper date overlap conditions, and use `least()` and `greatest()` to compute the overlapping range.

```
select 
    p1.player_id player_id_1,
    p2.player_id player_id_2,
    p1.team,
    greatest(p1.start_dt, p2.start_dt) start_dt,
    least(p1.end_dt, p2.end_dt) end_dt,
    least(p1.end_dt, p2.end_dt) - greatest(p1.start_dt, p2.start_dt) overlaps_interval
from players p1
inner join players p2
    on  p1.team = p2.team
    and p1.player_id < p2.player_id
    and coalesce(p1.end_dt, current_date) >= p2.start_dt
    and coalesce(p2.end_dt, current_date) >= p1.start_dt
order by 1, 2
```

I generally tend to avoid `overlaps`, because inequality conditions give more fine-grained control over whether the bounds are inclusive or exclusive. But if you wanted to use it, then:

```
select 
    p1.player_id player_id_1,
    p2.player_id player_id_2,
    p1.team,
    greatest(p1.start_dt, p2.start_dt) start_dt,
    least(p1.end_dt, p2.end_dt) end_dt,
    least(p1.end_dt, p2.end_dt) - greatest(p1.start_dt, p2.start_dt) overlaps_interval
from players p1
inner join players p2
    on  p1.team = p2.team
    and p1.player_id < p2.player_id
    and (p1.start_dt, coalesce(p1.end_dt, current_date)) 
        overlaps (p2.start_dt, coalesce(p2.end_dt, current_date))
order by 1, 2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=68c5c2937c41bc61fe3eed1cbd539257)** - both queries yield:

```
player_id_1 | player_id_2 | team   | start_dt   | end_dt     | overlaps_interval
----------: | ----------: | :----- | :--------- | :--------- | ----------------:
        100 |         101 | TEAM-B | 2018-11-15 | 2019-02-15 |                92
        100 |         102 | TEAM-B | 2018-11-15 | 2019-02-15 |                92
        101 |         102 | TEAM-A | 2019-11-01 | null       |              null
        101 |         102 | TEAM-B | 2018-05-15 | 2019-02-15 |               276
        101 |         102 | TEAM-C | 2019-05-15 | 2019-08-01 |                78
        101 |         103 | TEAM-C | 2019-04-01 | 2019-06-15 |                75
        102 |         103 | TEAM-C | 2019-05-15 | 2019-06-15 |                31
```